# notifyDataSetChanged on RecyclerView

Tags: json, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView and customAdaprer. I pass an list of an object (earthquakeList)to recycleradapter and then i do setAdapter:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    earthquakeList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(earthquakeList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I create AsyncTask on onResume method:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Kick off an {@link AsyncTask} to perform the network request
    new EarthQuakeAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

in AsyncTask my class i get a new List from my object that i get from internet and when I replaced this new list with older list and call notifyDataSetChanged, recyclerView still nothing show??
I debug my app and I get object from net.
I do in this way on list view but recylerview seems efferent.

I replace old list with the new list one like blow:

```
  private class EarthQuakeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,  List<Earthquake>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Earthquake> doInBackground(Void... urls) {

        // Create URL object
        URL url = HttpRequest.createUrl(USGS_REQUEST_URL);

        //  perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
        String jsonResponse = "";
        try {
            jsonResponse = HttpRequest.makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<Earthquake> earthquakes = HttpRequest.extractFeaturesFromJson(jsonResponse);
        return earthquakes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Earthquake> earthquakeList) {
        super.onPostExecute(earthquakeList);
        MainActivity.this.earthquakeList.clear();
        MainActivity.this.earthquakeList.addAll(earthquakeList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

what is exactly my wrong?

************************ EDIT ********************
this is Adapter :

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyHolder> {

List<Earthquake> earthquakes;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
    this.earthquakes = earthquakes;
}


@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.earthquak_list_item, parent, false);
    MyHolder myHolder = new MyHolder(view);
    return myHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {

    Earthquake earthquake = earthquakes.get(position);
    holder.magnitude.setText(earthquake.getmMagnitude());
    holder.location.setText(earthquake.getmLocation());
    holder.time.setText(earthquake.getmDate());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != earthquakes ? earthquakes.size() : 0);
}

public void setItems(List<Earthquake> earthquakeList) {
    this.earthquakes = earthquakeList;

}


public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.magnitude)
    TextView magnitude;

    @BindView(R.id.location)
    TextView location;

    @BindView(R.id.date)
    TextView time;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ops ,I forgot put **LayoutManager** for recyclerView .

this is right code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    earthquakeList = new ArrayList<>();
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(earthquakeList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```